# SYNTAX ERROR:GROUP BY clause cannot contain aggregations or window functions

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-athena

```
select json_extract(other_detail,'$.is_substitute_allowed') as substitute,
       count(date(order_date)) as order_date 
from prescription_metrics 
group by 1;
```

I am unable to group by over the extracted value from other_detail(which can be 0 or 1 only) in AWS Athena. 'other_detail' is a JSON while order_date is of type date. Error:

> GROUP BY clause cannot contain aggregations or window functions.

The query works fine when not using GROUP BY

Comment: `json_extract()` is not an aggregation or window function, so this query should not be generating that error.  Also, `count(date(order_date))` is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: json_extract can return a complex JSON object and you can get any position in that array, therefore, it is sort of a window function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use a nested query:

```
select substitute, order_date from 
(select json_extract(other_detail,'$.is_substitute_allowed') as substitute,
       count(date(order_date)) as order_date 
from prescription_metrics)
group by 1;
```

BTW, did you mean to have `count(distinct(order_date))` or any other date manipulation (`day` ?) on the order_date column?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query,

```
select json_extract(other_detail,'$.is_substitute_allowed') as substitute, count(date(order_date)) as order_date from prescription_metrics group by json_extract(other_detail,'$.is_substitute_allowed');
```

Comment: @MehulGupta . . . "not working" is not a helpful comment.  You need to explain why.  Does it return an error?  Does it return unexpected results?